# Can You Change the DPI of Pygame to Match that of Your Monitor?

Tags: python, pygame, screen-resolution, dpi

Pygame is currently running on a lower resolution than my screen. It seems to be using four pixels on my monitor for each pixel in the pygame screen (2x2 square). When I run the following code:

```
import pygame
pygame.init()
print(pygame.display.list_modes())
```

I get (2880,1800) as the maximum possible width and height for my screen. However, when I run:

```
screen = pygame.display.set_mode([2880, 1800])
screen.fill(white)
pygame.display.flip()
```

the window goes way off the boundaries of my screen. When I halve the values and set it to [1440,900], it fits my screen perfectly. I would like to fully utilize the resolution of my monitor, since the lines I'm drawing appear rather pixelated at this scale. Is there something I can do to fix this? I am running macOS Catalina 10.15.4 on a MacBook Pro.